# Destiny 2 Eater of Worlds with 4 Players

Tags: destiny-2

3 of my mates and I (4 total) attempted the Eater of Worlds raid lair for the first time last night. From past Destiny experience and even looking online, just about all raids were possible with this count.

Though, it seems like the raid lair is forcing 6 players in the "reactor" room. The one with the purple water and the platforms. We figured out that we need to jump on each one at a time in a line, but after getting to the 5th- 6th platform, no more will appear. The very first platform will turn red and eventually go down. By doing a bunch of jumping around, we can occasionally get 1 more platform to come up. Regardless, we cannot proceed past this point.

I looked up several guides, and not a single one discussed player count requirements or how to get past this with less than a full party. As well, we have been sure to follow the guides exactly as described.

Is this just a case where we absolutely have to have 6 players? Anyone have experience trying this with fewer players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried doing it with only 4 but with my experience doing it normal I don't believe it's possible. I've tried doing it multiple times after one person has fallen off and keep going with only 5 and it will end up stopping and you can't continue.

There are multiple videos showing how it's possible to skip parts or to do it solo, by using swords and supers to jump the gaps between reactors, but these will only get you to the last area with nothing happening. You have to get to the last plate on each section and have the "reactor temperature rises" message appear for each to actually progress and have the enemies spawn at the final area.

Comment: After doing various tests with 4 and 5 people, I can pretty much confirm that at least 5 people are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Every part of that raid besides the first part could be four man'd but I doubt ppl would be able to complete it unless extremely skilled. One case is the wipe phase on Argos with sustained DPS would be tough and the DPS phase in general will be a challenge for sure. You will definitely need to do two DPS phases per wipe phase. There are pictures online that depict the rotation and pattern of the orbs do you know what the next one will be in order to do that.